# How to stay on the same page without reloading on form submit in nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js

After form submit, I want to stay on the same page without reloading the page. Currently I'm using  redirect method & specifying the same html page name to redirect to the same page in nodejs post method. But it is reloading. We dont want to reload.

Comment: Use ajax for form submit. It makes an async call, so that page reload will not happen.

Comment: We forgot to mention that we should not use ajax here. instead we are using form submit & app.post. Can you please suggest some solution on this?

Comment: Is angularjs is used for front-end development?

Comment: No. we are using javascript only.

Comment: Then you must use ajax to avoid reloading the page, else its not possible.